Credo / AFJ error : [TypeError: 0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "did-resolver").parse is not a function (it is undefined)]
I am trying to run the following code to initialize a Credo / Aries Framework Javascript agent in React Native environment in an Expo ^50 version :
import {
  Agent,
  ConnectionEventTypes,
  ConnectionsModule,
  ConsoleLogger,
  DidExchangeState,
  LogLevel,
  MediationRecipientModule,
  MediatorPickupStrategy,
  KeyDerivationMethod,
  HttpOutboundTransport,
  WsOutboundTransport,
  InitConfig,
} from "@credo-ts/core"
import { agentDependencies } from "@credo-ts/react-native"
import { AskarModule } from "@credo-ts/askar"
import { ariesAskar } from "@hyperledger/aries-askar-react-native"

// and other irrelevant dependencies as well

const config: InitConfig = {
  label: "standalone-agent-10",
  walletConfig: {
    id: "standalone-agent-10",
    key: "00000000001000000000000000000010",
    keyDerivationMethod: KeyDerivationMethod.Argon2IMod,
  },
  logger: new ConsoleLogger(LogLevel.trace),
  // autoUpdateStorageOnStartup: true,
}

const mediatorInvitationUrl = "https://url...."



const agent = new Agent({
  config,
  modules: {
    askar: new AskarModule({ ariesAskar }),
    connections: new ConnectionsModule({ autoAcceptConnections: true }),
    mediationRecipient: new MediationRecipientModule({
      mediatorInvitationUrl,
      mediatorPickupStrategy: MediatorPickupStrategy.Implicit,
    }),
  },
  dependencies: agentDependencies,
})

agent.registerOutboundTransport(new WsOutboundTransport())
agent.registerOutboundTransport(new HttpOutboundTransport())

export const WelcomeScreenCredo = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
     agent
       .initialize()
       .then((_) => console.log("Agent initialized!"))
       .catch((err) => console.log("Agent not initialized:", err))
   }, [])

return <View>
<Text>Hi</Text>
<View>


 }



If i remove this snippet below, the code works perfectly fine and logs out Agent initialized! as expected:
    mediationRecipient: new MediationRecipientModule({
      mediatorInvitationUrl,
      mediatorPickupStrategy: MediatorPickupStrategy.Implicit,
    }),

But when I keep that snippet, I get the following error when I run yarn android:
 INFO  INFO: Creating agent with config {
  "agentConfig": {
    "label": "standalone-agent-10",
    "walletConfig": {
      "id": "standalone-agent-10",
      "key": "[*****]",
      "keyDerivationMethod": "ARGON2I_MOD",
      "storage": {}
    },
    "logger": 1,
    "agentDependencies": true
  }
}
 INFO  INFO: Initializing wallet 'standalone-agent-10' {
  "id": "standalone-agent-10",
  "key": "[*****]",
  "keyDerivationMethod": "ARGON2I_MOD",
  "storage": {}
}
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Wallet 'standalone-agent-10' opened with handle '1'
 INFO  INFO: Agent storage is up to date.
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Starting HTTP outbound transport
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Starting WS outbound transport
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Provision mediation with invitation {
  "mediatorInvitationUrl": "https://url...."
}
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Mediation connection does not exist, creating connection
 DEBUG  DEBUG: Routing created {
  "endpoints": [
    "didcomm:transport/queue"
  ],
  "routingKeys": [],
  "recipientKey": {
    "keyType": "ed25519",
    "publicKeyBase58": "----xyz----"
  }
}
 ERROR  Something went wrong while setting up the agent! Message: TypeError: 0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[1], "did-resolver").parse is not a function (it is undefined)



